# AWS Callout from VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, callout, aws, amazon-s3

**UPDATE**

---

Here is my updated Apex Code:

```
public class AmazonS3{
    public string AmazonS3Request { get; set; }
    public static void AmazonS3Request() {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('PUT');
        request.setEndpoint('callout:AWSS3');
        HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
        System.debug(response.getStatusCode());
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

I am getting this

```
HTTP Header Authorization=Not Set
```

and a 403 Error.

---

I have created a Named Credential within SF that stores the Authentication information for our AmazonS3 instance.

We have code that is working when the AmazonS3 credentials are stored directly within the VisualForce page, but, for obvious reasons, this is not ideal.

How can I have the VisualForce page access the information from the Named Credential easily?

I have reviewed SalesForce documentation and believe I am just missing a small piece, but cannot figure out what that is.  Any straightforward assistance is appreciated in this matter.

### ***Update***

---

This is my custom Apex code:

```
public class AmazonS3{
    public void AmazonS3Request() {
        String url = 'callout:AWS_S3';
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('PUT');
        request.setEndpoint(url);
        HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
    }
}
```

I am calling it in the VF page like this:

```
<apex:page controller="AmazonS3" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
```

And calling the method like this

```
{!AmazonS3Request}
```

The idea is the VF page takes an input of images from a user and uploads them to AmazonS3, creating its own folder based on the UniqueID entered by the user.

I am met with this error:

```
Error: Unknown property 'AmazonS3.AmazonS3Request'
```

Any idea what could be going on? Thanks in advance for the assistance!

---

We have created a Named Credential (AWS_S3) with all of the necessary authentications for Amazon S3 and tested in the developer's console this is functioning.

[Here is the tutorial followed for that.](https://www.sfdcpanther.com/integrate-salesforce-with-amazon-s3/)

My question now is - How do I make the callout request from our VisualForce page?
I think the connection just needs to be made here, so we don't have to hardcode in the authentications for AmazonS3.

I understand this is suggested:

```
String url = 'callout:AWS_S3';

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setEndpoint(url);
HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
```

***I'm just not sure where/how to implement this.***

The code is below.  We've searched multiple articles, and it seems like there has to be a straightforward link somewhere we are missing.

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleForImageUpload}"/>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.839.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>


//Bucket Configurations
var bucketName = " ";
var bucketRegion = "us-east-1";

            var s3 = new AWS.S3({
                apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
                params: {Bucket: bucketName}
        });
        
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newRow = row.insertCell(i);
    newRow.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    newRow.childNodes[0].value = "";
  }
}
function deleteRow(row) {
  var table = document.getElementById("data");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  if (rowCount > 1) {
    var rowIndex = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("data").deleteRow(rowIndex);
  }
  else {
    alert("Please specify at least one value.");
  }
}


async function s3upload() {
  var uniqueId,
  element = document.getElementById("uniqueId").value;
  if (element != "") {
      uniqueId = element;
  }
  else {
       alert("Please specify a Unique ID. This has been emailed to you.");
       return;
  }
  var updatedFileName = document.getElementsByClassName("updatedFileName");  
  var files = document.getElementsByClassName("uploadFile");
  function toArray(arr) {
    return [].slice.call(arr);
  }
  var files_arr = toArray(files).filter(v => v.files[0] != null);
  var actual_files = new Array();
  var errors_arr = new Array();
  files_arr.forEach(function callback(file_obj,i){
    actual_files[i] = file_obj.files[0]
  })   
  var updated_file_names_arr = toArray(updatedFileName);
  var image_count = actual_files.length;
  var final_image_index = image_count-1;
  var success_count = 0;
  var error_count = 0;
  var final_message = "";
  for ( var i = 0; i <= final_image_index; i++ ) {
    var file = actual_files[i];
    var fileName = updatedFileName[i].value; 
    var filePath = uniqueId + '/' + fileName + '.jpg';
    var fileUrl = 'https://' + bucketRegion + '.amazonaws.com/' + uniqueId + '/' +  filePath;
    var params = { Body: file, Key: filePath };
   try { 
      var result = await s3.upload(params).promise()
      console.log(result)
      var upload_success = true
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      var upload_success = false
    };
    if (upload_success == true) {
      success_count++;
    } else {
      error_count++;
      errors_arr.push(fileName);
    };
    var total_count = success_count + error_count;
    var uploaded_percent = 100 * total_count / image_count;
    document.getElementById("progress").value = uploaded_percent;
    if (uploaded_percent == 100) {
      var final_message = success_count + " images uploaded successfully. ";
      if (error_count != 0) {
          final_message += "Errors encountered uploading: ";
          final_message += errors_arr;
      };
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert(final_message);
      },5);
    };
  };
};
  
</script>
<br></br><br></br><br></br>
<div id="main">
  <h1>Please Upload Home Images</h1>
  <table id="header" class="data-table data-table-horizontal data-table-highlight">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> Please Enter Unique ID (Emailed to you)</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="uniqueId" value="" placeholder="Enter Unique ID" required="true"/></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="data" class="data-table data-table-horizontal data-table-highlight">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      
 </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>    
  <tr>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="top-buffer" onclick="addRow('data')" />
  </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <div class="pull-center">
<input type="button" class="top-buffer" value="Submit All Images" onclick="s3upload()" />
    </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <progress id="progress" max='100' value='0'></progress>
   
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </apex:page>
```

Comment: No - I think my question is simpler than that. I see the code for how the callout needs to be made in the link you provided.  However, I'm not sure where/how to use this.  Help in that direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a custom Apex controller associated with your VF page. The referenced Q&A has a code chunk that illustrates how to call AWS via Named Credentials in Apex.

Comment: Right - I come accross an 'invalid constructer' error - Do you have an example of how to write this Apex code and then reference it within the VF page?

Comment: You're trying it with a standard controller but you want a custom controller instead. Try following [this Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_custom_controllers)

Comment: I have attempted to update based on the direction from the Trailhead, but am still failing somewhere - I've updated my question above.  Are you able to assist in this particular use-case, without redirecting me? Thank you!

Comment: @identigral- Do you have any additional feedback/guidance?